# python pandas - modifying index dates

Tags: python, date, pandas

My pandas dataframe df has an index and a column 'A', where

```
type(df.index)
```

gives

```
pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex
```

How do i switch the numbers in the dates around, so that this:

```
                          A
 timestamp  
2015-03-05 13:51:00    71.000000
2015-03-05 13:52:00    71.600000
2015-03-05 13:53:00    72.500000
2015-03-05 13:54:00    73.142857
2015-03-05 13:55:00    77.625000
```

becomes this:

```
                          A
 timestamp  
03-05-2015 13:51:00    71.000000
03-05-2015 13:52:00    71.600000
03-05-2015 13:53:00    72.500000
03-05-2015 13:54:00    73.142857
03-05-2015 13:55:00    77.625000
```

Comment: You can't modify the datetime output format without converting to a string which is not useful as you can't perform arithmetic operations on strings like you can with datetimes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html), but then index type is string, not datetime:

```
#maybe is necessary swap %m with %d if first is day not month
df.index = df.index.strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')
print (df)
                             A
03-05-2015 13:51:00  71.000000
03-05-2015 13:52:00  71.600000
03-05-2015 13:53:00  72.500000
03-05-2015 13:54:00  73.142857
03-05-2015 13:55:00  77.625000

print (df.index)
Index(['03-05-2015 13:51:00', '03-05-2015 13:52:00', '03-05-2015 13:53:00',
       '03-05-2015 13:54:00', '03-05-2015 13:55:00'],
      dtype='object')

print (type(df.index[0]))
<class 'str'>
```